# c# comparing objects without creating dto

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, postsharp, serializable

Currently I am creating a `DTO` of an object to compare new and old values. It was fine when it was one object, but in the future that's going to change. I tried creating an `extension method` to `serialize` and `deserialize` for a deep copy, but `PostSharp` is throwing an error.

> Type
>   'PostSharp.Patterns.Model.NotifyPropertyChanged.ChangeTracking.ChildPropertyChangedProcessor'
>   in Assembly 'PostSharp.Patterns.Model, Version=4.2.28.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7f631e6ce13f078' is not marked as
>   serializable. (SerializationException)

Here is my extension method and the error is being thrown at  `formatter.Serialize(stream, source)`.

```
public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    if (ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (stream)
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this error or do I have to do this another way? If I do have to find another way what approach should I take?

Comment: Did you try upgrade to PostSharp 4.3? How does your class enhanced by NotifyPropertyChanged aspect look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) for this as well: (Every app should use it anyway, so what's the harm?)

```
var clone = new Poco();
Mapper.CreateMap<Poco, Poco>();
Mapper.Map<Poco, Poco>(source, clone);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many references to reflection based deep object graph comparison libraries; https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects as an example should do what you want without serialization

Comment: Would this actually create a deep copy as well?

Comment: No - but the method they use for walking the object tree can be easily adapted to create a copy.

Comment: Thanks for this I think it could come in handy in the future but AutoMapper might be a better solution for now.